# Calculate matrix using the rule of sarrus in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I want to do a program in C++ for calculate the determinant of a matrix using the rule of Sarrus. I need to use 'for' in the program and calculate primary and secondary diagonal. I have this:

```cpp
int main() {
    int matriz[3][3];

    cout << "Put the elements of 3x3 matrix:\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <3; j++) {
            printf("(%d,%d) = ", i, j);
            cin >> matriz[i][j];

        }
    }

    cout << "\nMatrix: \n\n";
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l <3; l++) {
            printf(" %d ", matriz[k][l]);
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    int prod=1, prox=0, linha = 0, coluna = 0;
        for ( int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            prod = prod * matriz[x][x];
        }
        cout << prod;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What's the problem with your existing code?

Comment: You have one diagonal right.. that is x=x so you go from left above to right below. But you will need more code than this. For 3x3 there are 3 diagonals, not one.. and to do Sarus, you will need right above to left below diagonals also. The right above to left below results are *subtracted* from the x=x result. . So you'll have to find a way to shift x -> (x+1) in your loop.. and when you reach the boundary of your matrix on the right, step back using x % 3. Underways, you'll have to sum the elements. Nice document: https://www.theoremoftheday.org/GeometryAndTrigonometry/Sarrus/TotDSarrus.pdf

Comment: Write a C ++ program that calculates the determinant of a 3-sided square matrix:
A. Receive the matrix filling values (200 pts)
B. Calculate the main and secondary diagonals and the determinant. (500 pts)
C. Print the completed matrix, in matrix format, and the determinant value (200 pts)
Comments:
i. Comment and indent your code (100 pts)
ii. Write your coding in a logical, clear and coherent way (1,000 pts)
iii. Diagonal calculations must be done using repetition structures (2,000 pts)
iv. Use Sarrus' Rule to solve!

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int matrix[3][3], i, j;
    int diagonal1 = 1,diagonal2 = 1,diagonal3 = 1;
    int diagonal4 = 1,diagonal5 = 1,diagonal6 = 1;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter the matrix elements : "<<endl;
    
    for(i =0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cout<<"a"<<i+1<<j+1<<" = ";
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"MATRIX :"<<endl;
    for(i =0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cout<<setw(5)<<matrix[i][j];;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"SARRUS FORM :"<<endl;
    for(i =0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cout<<setw(5)<<matrix[i][j];;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(i =0;i<2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cout<<setw(5)<<matrix[i][j];;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"DETERMINANT :"<<endl;
    for(i = 1;i<=3;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            //1stst diagonal
            if(i == j)
            {
                diagonal1*=matrix[i-1][j-1];
            }
            //2nd diagonal
            if( ((i*j == 2 || i*j ==6)  && i>j) || (i*j == 3 && i<j) ){
                diagonal2*=matrix[i-1][j-1];
            }
            //3rd diagonal
            if(((i*j == 2 || i*j ==6)  && i<j) || (i*j == 3 && i>j)){
                diagonal3*=matrix[i-1][j-1];
            }
        }
    }
    int sum1 = diagonal1 + diagonal2 + diagonal3;
    for(i = 1;i<=3;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            //1stst diagonal
            if(i*j == 3 || i*j == 4)
            {
                diagonal4*=matrix[i-1][j-1];
            }
            //2nd diagonal
            if(i*j == 1 || i*j == 6){
                diagonal5*=matrix[i-1][j-1];
            }
            //3rd diagonal
            if(i*j == 2 || i*j == 9){
                diagonal6*=matrix[i-1][j-1];
            }
        }
    }
    int sum2 = diagonal4 + diagonal5 + diagonal6;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<sum1-sum2<<endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```